# protoc generated header file has errors

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm getting strange outputs when I compile my `*.proto` file using the `protoc` compiler.

The `*.pb.h` and `*.pb.cc` files compile just fine, but the `*.pb.h` is riddled with syntax errors:

- inline specifier allowed on function declarations only
- expected a ')'
- 'struct': missing tag name
- And so on...

I'm not sure how to resolve this problem.  If there was something wrong with my `*.proto` file, I would get a compilation error I think?  How do I begin debugging this?

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to compile a C++ file with a C compiler. How are you compiling your source file that includes `*.pb.h`?

Comment: Well, I modified an older `*.proto` file to essentially include more fields.  The older generated `*.pb.h` file came out just  fine.  All the source code is being compiled in Visual Studio C++.